# Swipeview - show preview/snippet of next item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipeview

I am using `Swipeview` (http://cubiq.org/swipeview) to create a touch-enabled `carousel` working on an iPhone and Android. The basics works great.

My problem starts when i try to get it to show 25% of the next slide pr default. The idea is that the user can see 1/4 of the next slide/image, which should then make them slide the image to reveal the next slide/image. The first image then disapears, the second image becomes 100% visible, aligned to the left, and the 3rd image is then visible by 1/4. And so on.

I have tried changing the `div.style.cssText` (in `swipeview.js`) to have a width of `75%` instead of the default `100%`. This works for the initial load, but when i scroll, the part of the 2nd image that was visible on slide 1, is now hidden on slide 2.

I made a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/zeqjN/1/ (test it in Chrome and try dragging the image to the left)

Any ideas as to how i can modify `swipeview.js` to fit my needs?

Comment: like this? http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/visible-nearby/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with css only. Just add a scale effect on the items.

```
.scroller .scroll-item { float: left; -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1,1.1,1.1) }
```

Check out:
http://jsfiddle.net/frapporti/Xt9dM/